# Is PropertyDescriptor.IsBrowsable inconsistent with the associate Browsable() attribute?

Tags: c#, propertydescriptor

[`PropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cfx2yfs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is an abstract class from which custom property descriptors can inherit. The class has an `IsBrowsable` property, which, according to MSDN:

> Gets a value indicating whether the member is browsable, as specified in the BrowsableAttribute. (Inherited from MemberDescriptor.)

My question is, how is this property related to the `BrowsableAttribute` in `PropertyDescriptor.Attributes`, for the associated property (defined e.g. by adding the `[Browsable(false)]` decorator to the property?

My confusion arises from the fact that I managed to replace the `BrowsableAttribute` with `PropertyDescriptor.Attributes` a new one, which was inconsistent with `IsBrowsable`.

**Update**
Following Marc's answer, must I keep the `BrowsableAttribute` in sync with `IsBrowsable`? Are you aware of any controls which may look at one but not the other?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default PropertyDescriptor implementation uses reflection and looks at the BrowsableAttribute. However, if you are providing your own PropertyDescriptor implementation then *you are in charge* - there are very few things that need to be followed. If your custom implementation uses an unrelated way to determine what is / is not browsable : that is up to your implementation.